# Character escape sequence in javascript

Tags: javascript, escaping

Just noticed that some strings (taken from an array created from a m3u playlist file) won't work due to a malformed hexadecimal character escape sequence.

```
var strArray =  [
"#EXTM3U",
"C:\music\X Marks the Pedwalk - Desolation.mp3", //fine
"#EXTINF:287,Xandria - Ginger Sunset Expire", //fine
"C:\music\andria - Ginger Sunset Expire.mp3", //fine
"C:\music\xandria - Ginger Sunset Expire.mp3", // FAILS
"C:\\music\\xandria - Ginger Sunset Expire.mp3" //fine
]

alert (strArray);
```

I can get around it with escape slashes. But my question is what is actually causing the error. I thought it might be something to do with \x but that would mean the first track would also fail. So I'm a little bit confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I thought it might be something to do with \x but that would mean the first track would also fail.

No, because `x` and `X` are not the same character. :-) `\x` (with the `x` in lower case) [is special in string literals](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.8.4), `\X` (with the `X` in upper case) is not.

Best practice is to *always* escape backslashes that are meant to really be backslashes as opposed to the beginning of an escape sequence. Otherwise, you *will* trip yourself up.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace backslashes with the function str_replace..

```
<?php

$bodytag = str_replace("%body%", "black", "<body text='%body%'>");

// Produce: <body text='black'>
```

http://php.net/manual/es/function.str-replace.php